# Drawing diagram in html page

Tags: html

I like to draw in a HTML page. The diagram might contain dots,lines,polygons,circles,eclipse etc. Which is the best way to do this. I want the solution to load very fast in websites. could you help me with a solution with an example

Comment: SVG is a good option as mentioned in the answer below.Another option is using Canvas.

Comment: Using a canvas means using JavaScript, which means plugins, which means more capabilities (such as 3D animations). But SVG can be manipulated by CSS3, which also means 3D animations and such. Therefore, SVG is the better option because it can be done out-of-the-box with pretty much any browser (it's a W3C standard).

Answer (score 3):

Use an [**SVG** (Scalable Vector Graphic)](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp). It's exactly what you're looking for, and more.

```html
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
  <ellipse cx="250" cy="60" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill: yellow; stroke:purple; stroke-width: 2" />
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  <polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
  <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3" />
  <text x="200" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(30 20,40)">I love SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain SVG is a good solution if you want to display something that you have already drawn.

On the other hand, if you want users to do their own drawing, it would be a lot easier to use libraries designed to draw diagrams. Such libraries can use either SVG or Canvas internally, it doesn't matter too much, since the point is not having to learn SVG or Canvas.

An example of such a library is one I created, GoJS. See examples at http://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html.